# PhoneGap BlackBerry App - SignatureTool.jar Freeze

Tags: cordova, blackberry-webworks

I am using JDK 7.0, BlackBerry WebWorks SDK 2.3.1.5

When I try to build and deploy the bb phonegap application in the command prompt using ant blackberry load-device,  it does some compilation and launches the Signature tool, but within few seconds of launching, the signature tool stops responding. But it does send all signing requests to server and I get a bunch of emails from RIM confirming the success of signing requests. The tool doesn't respond at all and I have to kill the process.

Has anyone else experienced same/similar issue? If not, can anyone give me some pointers to fix this issue?

Comment: When I switched back to JDK 1.6.0 (aka JDK 6.0) it worked !!!

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem but my findings revealed to me that it was no problem. What happened was that your java version is higher than the version used to compile signatureTool.jar. so the simple fix is to either 
1. upgrade an equivalent webworks jdk or 
2. downgrade your java jdk version.
 I detest downgrading so rather i'll upgrade my webworks jdk. And instead of downloding from scratch i'll just replace the signatureTool.jar with a newer one. Here's the download link [signatureTool.jar](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/rim/attachments/rim/java_dev/192472/1/SignatureTool.zip).
Thank [him](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Signature-Tool-freezes-during-signing/td-p/1315631) for sharing the info and the download link and if you so wish thank me for bringing the solution to stackoverflow *smiles*. It worked for me like voodoo.